# How can I change this from dynamically obtained category ID to specified one?

Tags: category, php, magento-1.8, static-block

I'm pulling my hair out over this, and can't figure why it's not working.

I've got a script that displays all subcategories for the current category. But now I want to change it so I can specify a category ID at the start of the php file, and have the script show all subcategories for that ID.

```
<?php
/* File Location
* /new/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/navigation
*/
?>

<div id="categories">
<div class="col_full">
<div class="listing" >

<?php 

function getImageUrl($category)
{
$cur_category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category);

        $url = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getImageUrl();
    return $url;
};

//Get the Current Category
$_maincategorylisting=$this->getCurrentCategory();    

// Iterate all categories in store
foreach ($this->getCurrentChildCategories() as $_category):

    // If category is Active
    if($_category->getIsActive()):

        // Load the actual category object for this category
        $cur_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());

        // Load a random product from this category
        $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addCategoryFilter($cur_category);
        $products->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'))->limit(1);

        $products->load();

        // This a bit of a fudge - there's only one element in the collection
        $_product = null;

        foreach ( $products as $_product ) {}

        if(isset($_product)):
        ?>

        <div class="sub-category-listing" style="float: left; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; padding: 0px; text-align: center; width: 155px; ">
            <div class="linkimage"><p><a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category)?>" class="product-image">

        <?php
        $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
        $layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category);
        ?>      

        <?
        // If there is an image set for the category - Display it
        if($_imgUrl=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getThumbnail()):?>
            <?php $_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory(); ?>
            <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$_category->getThumbnail()  ?>" style="max-width:120px; max-height:120px; padding: 10px;" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?
        // If there is not a image set for that Category - Display a random product Image
        if(!$_imgUrl): 

        // Let's load the category Model and grab the product collection of that category

        $product_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId())->getProductCollection();
        $product_collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'))->limit(1);

        // Now let's loop through the product collection and print the ID of every product
        foreach($product_collection as $product) {

        // Get the product ID
        $product_id = $product->getId();

        // Load the full product model based on the product ID

        $full_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

        // Now that we loaded the full product model, let's access all of it's data

        // Let's get the Product Name

        $product_name = $full_product->getName();

        // Let's get the Product URL path

        $product_url = $full_product->getProductUrl();

        // Let's get the Product Image URL

        $product_image_url = $full_product->getImageUrl();

        // Let's print the product information we gathered and continue onto the next one

        } //End For Each
        ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $product_image_url; ?>" width="135" height="135"  style="padding: 10px;" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        </a>
            </div>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category)?>">
        <h2 class="product-name" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><?php echo $_category->getName()?></a></h2>

        </div>

        <?php
        endif;
    endif;
endforeach;
?>
```

I've been told it's around line 26/27 that I want to change (where $this states what category to use) but nothing I try seems to set the category ID. Most things I try end up in the actual page saying Fatal Error: call to a non-member object

Can someone please help me..?
I was thinking it would be as simple as entering a variable with the id right at the start, and then using that variable throughout inplace of 'get current category'

**UPDATE:** visible link can be seen at www.gadgetclinic.co.uk/home - You can see it starts by saying Repairs, as this is the first category but I just want to show items inside this 'Repairs' category (category id is 19). If you click on Repairs, you can see subcats. These are what I Want to display.

**UPDATE:** Sorry, visible link wasn't showing block, but it now is. If anyone can help, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Can anyone help me please with this?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this code will figure out to get n level of subcategory.

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <ul id="nav">
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                    <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
                </a>
                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
            <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

For More Details Refer this  [link for css](http://shahkeyul.wordpress.com/2013/03/31/how-to-get-all-category-and-sub-category-in-navigation-menu-dynamically-in-magento)